# Welcoming of Bot not working because of "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

Tags: bots, discord.js

Ok so I want my bot to welcome new users in a channel for welcoming, so I used `find`. Here is what I got so far:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
let guild = member.guild;
guild.channel.find('name','welcome','welcoming','greeting','general').send(`AYYY! Welcome ${member.user} to our Discord Server! Check out the FAQ, Info, and/or The Rules channels (if there is) for some documentation and support to help you get ready!`);
});
```

Expected result: Welcomes the user in the channel that was used `find` on.

Actual Result: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined.

I tried a lot of things, but the results are the same. Also, `channels` didn't not work, only `channel`.

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` are you using?

Comment: i think its the new one

Comment: .find is a method on Array. It looks like guild.channel is undefined (does not exists/is not set) Maybe try to console.log the member so you can see wich properties do exist on member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also don't believe you can use `.find()` to return multiple channels, since it always returns the first element it finds in the array.

You can, however, create another array that is a filter of `guild.channels.cache` based on channel names and then use `.forEach()` on that array to send a message to each of them like so:

```
function channelNamesFilter(channel) {
    let channelNames = ['name','welcome','welcoming','greeting','general'];

    if(channelNames.includes(channel.name)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

let filteredChannels = guild.channels.cache.filter(channelNamesFilter);
filteredChannels.forEach(element => element.send('AYYY! Welcome ${member.user.name} to our Discord Server! Check out the FAQ, Info, and/or The Rules channels (if there is) for some documentation and support to help you get ready!'));
```

Notice too how I changed `${member.user}` to `${member.user.name}`, the first one is an object  the second one is its name property in string form.

Answer (score 0):

It's guild.channel**s** with a **s** and you have to use the [cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=cache) so your code would be:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
let guild = member.guild;
guild.channels.cache.find('name','welcome','welcoming','greeting','general').send(`AYYY! Welcome ${member.user} to our Discord Server! Check out the FAQ, Info, and/or The Rules channels (if there is) for some documentation and support to help you get ready!`);
});
```

Edit:
You can't find multiple channels. You have to put only one name.

Comment: it didnt work, now i got this: fn = fn.bind(thisArg); fn.bind is not a function

Comment: it said its from `C:\Users\63929\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:158`

Comment: I'm not sure that you can find multiple channels at the same time try with only one.

Comment: Try using ```channel=> channel.name=== '...'``` or ```"name", "..."```